# React native blur effect with css

Tags: react-native

How can I implement blur effect into my code with css and using `View` component. I tried it to find , but at the end I encountered with a lt of libraries.How should i implement this without any library.Could anyone possibly help me ? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Need to know what it is you're trying to blur; there are a number of different approaches depending on if it's text/image etc.

Comment: You can use `blurRadius` with `Image`, otherwise you need to use a library `react-native-blur`